# Create a new array from objects with random structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, recursion

I want to make a new array from a JSON. The problem is I don't know the structure of the JSON I will be getting. It could be anything. But I know the JSON's key which will contain all the data I will need for the new array. For example say that key is 'data' and it is the array that contains all the data I need. Besides that, I will have to look for 'customerName', 'customerAddress' and 'customerAge' in that JSON array with key 'data'. And I will create the new array with those keys' values. So the new array so should look like this:

```
[
    {
         name: '', // it will be customerName from the JSON
         address: '', // it will be customerAddress from the JSON
         age: '', // it will be customerAge from the JSON
     },
     {
         // more objects
     }
]
```

Please note that customerName, customerAddress and customerAge could exist in nested arrays or objects in the 'data' array in JSON. So I have to look for them.

I have created a recursive function for it but it is returning an empty array.

This is what I tried:

```js
function extractDataFromJSON(json, key) {
    const result = [];

    function findData(obj) {
        if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
            for (const item of obj) {
                findData(item);
            }
        } else if (obj && typeof obj === 'object') {
            if (key in obj) {
                if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
                    for (const item of obj[key]) {
                        findData(item);
                    }
                } else if (
                    'customerName' in obj[key] &&
                    'customerAddress' in obj[key] &&
                    'customerAge' in obj[key]
                ) {
                    const { customerName, customerAddress, customerAge } = obj[key];
                    result.push({
                        name: customerName || '',
                        address: customerAddress || '',
                        age: customerAge || '',
                    });
                }
            } else {
                for (const prop in obj) {
                    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && typeof obj[prop] === 'object') {
                        findData(obj[prop]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    findData(json);
    return result;
}

const jsonData1 = {
    data: [
        {
            customerName: 'John Doe',
            customerAddress: '123 Main St',
            customerAge: 30,
        },
        {
            customerName: 'Jane Smith',
            customerAddress: '456 Maple Ave',
            customerAge: 25,
        },
        // ... other data ...
    ],
};

// const jsonData2 = [
//     {
//          data: [
//                  {
//                      customerName: 'John Doe',
//                      customerAddress: '123 Main St',
//                      customerAge: 30,
//                 },
//                 {
//                      customerName: 'Jane Smith',
//                      customerAddress: '456 Maple Ave',
//                      customerAge: 25,
//                 },
//                 // ... other data ...
//          ],
//     }
// ];

// const jsonData3 = {
//     data: [
//         {
//             customerName: 'John Doe',
//             customerAge: 30,
//             address: {
//                 customerAddress: '123 Main St',
//             }
//         },
//         {
//             customerName: 'Jane Smith',
//             customerAge: 30,
//             address: {
//                 customerAddress: '456 Maple Ave',
//             }
//         },
//     ],
// };



const newArray = extractDataFromJSON(jsonData1, 'data');
console.log(newArray);
```

I have also added 2 other objects as tests to check if my function works with those type of structures as well.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

UPDATE

```
const jsonData1 = {
    data: [
        {
            customerName: 'John Doe',
            customerAddress: '123 Main St',
            customerAge: 30,
        },
        {
            customerName: 'Jane Smith',
            customerAddress: '456 Maple Ave',
            customerAge: 25,
        },
        // ... other data ...
    ],
    data2: [
        {
            customerName: 'John Doe2',
            customerAddress: '123 Mainsss St',
            customerAge: 30,
        },
        {
            customerName: 'Jane Smith3',
            customerAddress: '456 Mapleaaa Ave',
            customerAge: 25,
        },
        // ... other data ...
    ],
};
```

Comment: You copied and pasted this code from Chat GPT and as it's not working as per expectation you asked it here. That's the reason we always suggest that we should believe in SO for a solutions from Subject matter experts instead of a system.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal, where does this claim come from? Are you sitting next to Zak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same function for recursion, just pass the result array to it.
There some trick here to collect the nested object properties - we provide `acc` (a property accumulator) argument to collect the properties in the descendants:

**IMPORTANT REMARK**
The OP wants all fields collected:

```
                    'customerName' in obj[key] &&
                    'customerAddress' in obj[key] &&
                    'customerAge' in obj[key]
```

So this case won't be collected, since the field name is duplicated:

```
//             customerName: 'Jane Smith',
//             customerAddress: '456 Maple Ave',
//             address: {
//                 customerAddress: '456 Maple Ave',
//             }
```

I supposed that's an error. Moreover the code doesn't try to find duplicates and uses the first found property. It would be weird if the data contains duplicates imho...

```js
function extractDataFromJSON(obj, fields, result = [], acc = null) {

    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        for (const item of obj) {
            extractDataFromJSON(item, fields, result, acc);
        }
    } else if (obj && typeof obj === 'object') {

        const keys = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => fields[key]);
        const fieldsLen = Object.keys(fields).length;

        if (keys.length) {

            const item = acc || {};

            for (const key in obj) {
                if (fields[key]) {
                    item[fields[key]] = obj[key] || '';
                    continue;
                }
                // check the property if the object is incomplete
                keys.length < fieldsLen && extractDataFromJSON(obj[key], fields, null, item);
            }
            // push only complete items and if the result array is present 
            // (not the collecting properties mode)
            if(result && Object.keys(item).length === fieldsLen){
                result.push(item);
            }

        } else {
            for (const key in obj) {
                extractDataFromJSON(obj[key], fields, result, acc);
            }
        }

    }
    return result;

}

const jsonData1 = {
    data: [
        {
            customerName: 'John Doe',
            customerAddress: '123 Main St',
            customerAge: 30,
        },
        {
            customerName: 'Jane Smith',
            customerAddress: '456 Maple Ave',
            customerAge: 25,
        },
        // ... other data ...
    ],
    data2: [
        {
            customerName: 'John Doe2',
            customerAddress: '123 Mainsss St',
            customerAge: 30,
        },
        {
            customerName: 'Jane Smith3',
            customerAddress: '456 Mapleaaa Ave',
            customerAge: 25,
        },
        // ... other data ...
    ],
};

const jsonData3 = [{
    differentKey: [
        {
            customerName: 'John Doe',
            customerAge: 30,
            iAmDummy: [{ dummyArray: [null, undefined, '', false, new Date] }],
            customerAddress: '123 Main St'
        },
        {
            customerName: 'Jane Smith',
            iAmDummy: [{ dummyArray: [null, undefined, '', false, new Date] }],
            lookDeeper: {customerAge: 40},
            address: [{
                customerAddress: '456 Maple Ave',
            }]
        },
    ],
}];


const newArray1 = extractDataFromJSON(jsonData1, {customerName: 'name', customerAddress: 'address', customerAge: 'age'});
console.log(newArray1);

const newArray3 = extractDataFromJSON(jsonData3, {customerName: 'name', customerAddress: 'address', customerAge: 'age'});
console.log(newArray3);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. However, I'm getting an error for the 3rd jsonData. This is the error `TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'customerName' in John Doe`. But the first two is passing.

Comment: @Zak fixed, also added handling of `address: {customerAddress: '456 Maple Ave'`

Comment: Okay I just tested it. New issues. the first two is returning two objects but the last one is returning only one object. And also, all the objects keys are not 'name', 'address' and 'age'

Comment: @Zak i've explained in the answer, updated

Comment: @Zak so the problem solved, at least working, wouldn't say it's extremely optimized for speed, but the logic seems ok

Comment: I am extremely sorry, I mistakenly added a duplicated key in the last data object.

Comment: what about using my own keys in the new array? And what can I do to optimize it?

Comment: @Zak `{customerName: 'name', customerAddress: 'address', customerAge: 'age'}` - change the mapping to whatever you like. basically you map `customerName -> name`. both can be anything. I don't think you should bother with optimization unless you have `data` as an array with more than 10000 elements

Comment: Thanks. That will help. But I will bother you a bit more. I think you have overlooked that the data will have a key name that will be the actual array I will be getting the data from. This key name could be anything. So in my example I tried with 'data'. But it could be something like 'response' or whatever. Can you cover that part as well please?

Comment: @Zak forgot to save, updated

Comment: Yes I will select the answer but can you please help me out with this? Check the OP for the new data structure. What of there is two different arrays in the example data that includes same type of fields and I only want to extract from say the first? I will know the name(key) of the array beforehand. So I can target that only. Right now if that structure is like that then I get the data from that second list as well, which I dont want.

Comment: @Zak as i said the structure doesn't matter, i've updated the answer

Comment: Thanks, I'll figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The [`JSON.parse` reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#using_the_reviver_parameter) and [`JSON.stringify` replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter) can be used to process nested values :

```js
const jsonData1 = { data: [
        { customerName: 'John Doe', customerAddress: '123 Main St', customerAge: 30, },
        { customerName: 'Jane Smith', customerAddress: '456 Maple Ave', customerAge: 25, },
    ], data2: [ 
        { customerName: 'John Doe2', customerAddress: '123 Mainsss St', customerAge: 30, },
        { customerName: 'Jane Smith3', customerAddress: '456 Mapleaaa Ave', customerAge: 25, }, ], };
        
const result = [];

JSON.stringify(jsonData1, (k, v) => v.customerName ? result.push(v) : v);

console.log( JSON.stringify( result ).replaceAll('},', '},\n ') );
console.table( result );
```